# HTML Website icon / favicon

Tags: html, image, icons, favicon

What's best for a favicon for my website, .png or .ico? What's the difference, browser-crossing and compatibility? Tell me everything please, I wanna know what's best. Also I'd like to know if it's the same if I use an image 16x16 or if I use it bigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use [Real Favicon Generator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/) for that. Favicons are complicated (different sizes for different devices etc.). This site can generate you necessary images and HTML code.